# 500 Internal Server Error with curl

Tags: php, curl

I've run out of ideas of what might causes the 500 Internal Server Error with cURL

```
$someString = '7abcd684efg1hi085b7b47dc4e508e99a5edcba9';
$url = 'http://192.168.254.211:8080/sampleProject/auth/logout/'.$someString;
$logoutCurl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($logoutCurl, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        // CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json', 
            'jrr: '.$jrr, 
            'slave: '.$slave,
            'spoil: '.$spoil
        )
    )
);
curl_exec($logoutCurl);
curl_close($logoutCurl);
```

It keeps on giving me the Internal Server error, and it says that it doesn't actually call the server, but I'm sure I'm properly connected to the server as I can successfully login.

Some notes:
`$someString` is a string added to the url as it is required by the server.
`$jrr`,`$slave`, and `$spoil` are required to be pass.
the server doesn't return or respond anything, I just need to get the 200 status.
Is there something that I'm missing out on cURL?

thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can check the logs on the remote machine?

Comment: according to the server admin, the program doesn't access the url for logout cause no logs are added, unlike in log in.

Comment: I tried using `curl_error` and it gave me a 400 Bad Request Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `CURLOPT_POST => true` as I don't actually pass a variable to the page which is why I think `curl_error` gives me `400 Bad Request`.